# Grain Bill for 5 Gallon (Wheat and Barley Pale Ale)

Tags: all-grain, recipe, recipe-formulation

I am new to home brewing and would welcome the insights and comments of the other home brewers on this website in order to brew a 5 gallon batch of a Wheat and Barley based Pale Ale.

That said, what would be the typical grain bill be (for a 5 gallon brew) as well as the water ratios (mash in vs mash out).

Much thanks and appreciation for everyone's help and support.

Jay

Comment: Are you brewing with all grain or extract?

Comment: What is the ABV (alcohol percentage) you want? Do you know which yeast you want to use? These are basically the first two parameters that will define the amount of malt (both types) you will need. If you want to use wheat, you can vary between 0% (none) and 70%. The 70% is based upon my own experiences. Since wheat has no husk, you need the barley husks to filter.

Comment: After the ABV and yeast, is the question of hops. How bitter do you like your pale ale? How much flavour and aroma do you want of your hops? Do you have a preference, or are you limited by what you can buy?

Comment: In another group this would probably be marked as "opinion based" question, but I like to help out beginners with brewing.